# Symfony2.8 API + Login Form

Tags: rest, symfony

I have a website that uses Symfony2.8; I am working on a mobile app that would use the same project as the backend so I need to support token based authentication as well as regular login forms. All resources I've found talk about API only authentication not API(token based) and form. Anyone has any ideas how to accomplish this?

I am using FOSUserBundle if that matters.

Comment: Your issues it's about FosUser or the reset API ! Can you add more details

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using custom Authenticators for each case.

Symfony 2.8 [introduced Guard](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-guard-authentication-component), which makes it's relatively easy to create custom Authenticators.

Basically you create 2 custom Authenticators , which essentially means creating 2 Services.

1. FormLoginAuthenticator -> app.form_login_authenticator
2. ApiTokenAuthenticator -> app.api_token_authenticator

Once these services are created, you just have to register those as Authenticators

in `app/config/security.yml`

`security:
    ...
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        knpu_guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.form_login_authenticator
                - app.api_token_authenticator
             entry_point: app.form_login_authenticator`

Obviously it's upto you to implement those Services, but Symfony Docs does provide a decent starting point for you to start .

Check these links for the same :

- [How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/guard_authentication.html)
- [How to Use Multiple Guard Authenticators](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/multiple_guard_authenticators.html)
- https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/guard ( provides fully working example +  tutorial )